# Get page content after completely loaded

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I am using C# windows application to get a web page HTML content but the returned content is not completed (the news list is missing as it loaded using java script). I added a webBrowser control and navigate to the URL that I want to get it content and in documentDompleted event I get the documentText which is missing some HTML tags.I tried all the solutions in stackoverflow but they failed. Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = textBoxURL.Text.Trim();
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(url);

    }


    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string content = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
    }
}
```

and this is the URL I am trying to get its content:

http://search.youm7.com/home/Index?allwords=%D8%B3%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%87%D8%B6%D9%87

Answer (score 0):

Using javascrip you can use windowOnload() function, this function alows you to load the pages when all the contents of the script are charge!

You can get more information there: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: I am using a windows form application to obtain the HTML content of this page, I just can use the events of the WebBrowser Contol.